What am I doing wrong when trying to have Gradle (Kotlin) generate a zip file?
I'd like to use Gradle to package two .java files in a .zip file - so I added to my build.gradle.ktl file the following code. I have no build errors and running ./gradlew assemble --dry-run I can see the new task being executed, but I actually don't see the expected .zip file (anywhere, not just on desktop as expected). Anything I could be missing / doing incorrectly? Thanks!
tasks.register<Zip>("packageFiles") {
    from("bootrecoverybackend/src/main/java/mbr_backend/Closer.java")
    from("bootrecoverybackend/src/main/java/mbr_backend/SambaThread.java")
    archiveFileName.set("zippedFiles.zip")
    destinationDirectory.set(file("/Users/c11886/desktop")) // NOPE :(
}

tasks.named("assemble") {
    dependsOn("packageFiles")
}

I tried a code from answers to similar "how to package" questions on Stackoverflow. I was expecting a .zip file being generated and put on desktop, but no .zip file is generated or put anywhere in my machine

Ah! Found it .. should have used the full path for the files to be zipped: /Users/c11886/VSCodeProjects etc. Thanks everyone for your time!
